# How to use gflags with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like the FindGflags module is broken/non-existant

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222016/how-to-use-gflags-with-ubuntu-14.04/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2015-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm so glad you asked Dave, turns out, according to the [gflags developer](https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/issues/36):

> This is more likely a problem of the Debian/Ubuntu package. Even though it suggests to contain gflags version 2.1, it's more likely version 2.0 given the list of files which was still using the auto tools for the build and installation. Or, the package maintainer decided to use the new source files with the old packaging tools. This, however, seems unreasonable given that there are no particular code changes besides the transition to CMake between these versions.

So we've added a [FindGflags rule to cmake_modules](https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/issues/36) in ROS Jade.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2015-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1